# How would I draw this shape in Android using xml?

Tags: android, ios, xml, uitableview

I'm porting one of my iOS apps over to Android (which I'm pretty new to), and I was wondering how I would draw this shape in Android using XML:

[image]

I want to recreate the shape (the white object) at the bottom of a tableView. The image attached is a screenshot of the bottom of a UITableView.

Any help would be greatly appreciated if you need any more info just let me know.

Thanks

EDIT:

Sorry I wasn't totally clear, I'm actually trying to recreate the slight arch at the bottom of the table. Since it's so slight, you may not be able to see it with a quick glance.

Answer (score 0):

It seams to me that you want to "lift" your table up a little bit. If so, you have to implement this attribute to your tableView:

```
android:elevation="2dp"
```

or in java:

```
tableview.setElevation(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

My opinion when reading this question: Stop trying to make your android apps look like iOS apps !!!

If you still want to do it. 
Just have the background color for your activity to that color and set the layout_margin to either 2 or 4. 
It should give you your desired effect.

Comment: Yeah my boss wants it to look like my iOS version.